# Composite C1 - Page template - Media folder placeholder

Tags: asp.net, c1-cms

Just downloaded Composite C1 one week ago, and started to learning functionality of this IMHO really good piece of software.

I have done a setup of Open Cph site, and started to building a web site. 
Successfully integrated Composite with Visual Studio 2013, I am referencing issues to specify a media folder for Bootstrap carousel via page design mode.

This is what I did for getting this feature done :

Make a custom page template -> Called DestinationPage, where I have a 

`@Function("Composite.Media.BootstrapCarousel" ,  new { ImagesFolder = this.ImagesFolder})`

Unfortunately, this whole morning I am trying to figure out how to pass this.ImageFolder value 
from LayoutPage to DestinationPage with PlaceHolders. Is there any possibility when editing 
a page to have a placeholder where you can pickup or choose a media folder?

I want to specify for each page a different media folder where BootstrapCarousel will
pick up images.

Anybody have solution for this?
I have several ideas on my mind, but as I said I am not experienced with Composite....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at creating a Page Metadatatype which will show up on a new Metadata tab when editing a page.

These are two good articles about Page metadata

- [Adding Metadata Fields](http://docs.composite.net/Layout/Page-Types/Adding-Metadata-Fields)
- [Filtering datatypes with metadata](http://docs.composite.net/Data/Metadata-filtering/Filtering-datatypes-with-metadata)

Comment: Great and thank you. Just one info, if you are developing C1 as web   project, be sure that reference to Composite.Generated.dll is added .

Comment: @FranoHartman even better, be sure to make your datatypes as static - that is as an Interface directly in your code. That way you don't need to reference Composite.Generated.dll ever.